Reaching high windows on pebble dash house
Without getting into a “who loves pebble dash” discussion…
I’d like to reach the exterior windows on our second floor. I can wash them with a telescoping rod, but I need to replace the spline in the screens.
I don’t want to lean a ladder against the house itself because it would knock pebbles off. Or, worse, crack the substrate.
Any suggestions as to how best to reach these? What kinda of ladders? Or is there a better trick?
Thanks!

You take the screens out, place them on a flat surface, remove the existing spline, roll in new spline and put the screens back. Any other method risks serious injury.

I tape old rags around the top of my ladders to make a cushion to protect whatever the ladder is leaning on.  Still best to take the screens out to re-screen them.

Can you not take them out from the inside? I've always fixed window screens that way.

@RMDman yep, basically cushion the top of the ladder.  If you have an old pillow or seating foam, you can basically wrap the top of the ladder in it.
